# Rust Serde create deserializer for Option::<String>

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I have two custom functions used for serde `deserialize_with`

```
// Converts string to u32
pub fn de_u32_from_str<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u32, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    s.parse::<u32>().map_err(de::Error::custom)
}

// Converts string that may be `null` to either `Some(u32)` or `None`
pub fn de_opt_u32_from_opt_str<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<u32>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s = Option::<String>::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    s.map(|s| s.parse::<u32>().map_err(de::Error::custom))
        .transpose()
}
```

I tested `de_u32_from_str` like this:

```
fn deserialize_u32_from_str(string: &str, expected: u32) {
    let de: StrDeserializer<ValueError> = string.into_deserializer();
    let result = de_u32_from_str(de).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(result, expected);
}
```

However I struggle creating `deserializer` for testing `de_opt_u32_from_opt_str`

```
fn deserialize_opt_u32_from_opt_str(maybe_string: Option<&str>, expected: Option<u32>) {
    // I need a `deserializer` here
    let de: ... = ...;
    let result = de_opt_u32_from_opt_str(de).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(result, expected);
}
```

**How can I create a deserializer like**

```
let de: StrDeserializer<ValueError> = string.into_deserializer();
```

**but holding `Option<String>`to satisfy**

```
let s = Option::<String>::deserialize(deserializer)?;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: @Stargateur They want to create a deserializer that always gives a specific `Option<String>`, like [`StrDeserializer`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/value/struct.StrDeserializer.html) but for `Option<String>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a deserializer for `Option` that will work with any type that implements `IntoDeserializer` (built to mimic the existing implementations in `serde::de::value`):

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

use serde::de::{Deserializer, Error, IntoDeserializer, Visitor}; // 1.0.160

struct OptionDeserializer<T, E> {
    value: Option<T>,
    marker: PhantomData<E>,
}

impl<T, E> OptionDeserializer<T, E> {
    pub fn new(value: Option<T>) -> Self {
        OptionDeserializer {
            value,
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'de, T, E> Deserializer<'de> for OptionDeserializer<T, E>
where
    T: IntoDeserializer<'de, E>,
    E: Error,
{
    type Error = E;

    fn deserialize_any<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>,
    {
        match self.value {
            Some(value) => visitor.visit_some(value.into_deserializer()),
            None => visitor.visit_none(),
        }
    }

    serde::forward_to_deserialize_any! {
        bool i8 i16 i32 i64 i128 u8 u16 u32 u64 u128 f32 f64 char str string
        bytes byte_buf option unit unit_struct newtype_struct seq tuple
        tuple_struct map struct enum identifier ignored_any
    }
}
```

Using it, the missing line in your function would be:

```
let de: OptionDeserializer<&str, ValueError> = OptionDeserializer::new(maybe_string);
```

See a full demo with tests on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c84a439458cb2622eaa550768f4e1a24).